# Play scala not reading cookies

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework

I am trying to print all cookies in play scala application.

```
requestHeader.cookies.foreach { cookie : Cookie => println(cookie.name) }
```

But it prints nothing.Surprising size of cookie map is 0

```
println(requestHeader.cookies.size)
```

There are a lot of cookies in Safari.

Above code is in a Filter

```
object SecurityFilter extends Filter{

   def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])
       (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
       println(requestHeader.cookies.size)
   }
 }
```

Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Resolved the problem. Was on localhost hence it was not recognizing the cookies. Pointed 127.0.0.1 to host.domain.com in /etc/hosts and it started printing non-secured cookies

Answer (score 0):

As CodeBucket points out in his/her own comment, you will need to modify the the hosts file to ensure being able to see cookies. I was unfamiliar with the hosts file so I thought I'd write here in case others are also unfamiliar with it.

For example, if you're running Windows 8, the hosts file is located in the following path:
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

You will need to add the localhost IP address and a proxy address to this file. Once you do that, then you can use the proxy address instead of the IP address. You should then see the cookies.

Here's more info about modifying the hosts file on various platforms:
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file